# Firebase 9, Vue 3 Merge data does not work

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to merge data (not overwrite) in my firebase db. Therefore I had a look at the following document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

And I tried to do the same with my setDoc but it doesn't work. I always get an error (Uncaught TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function). As far as I understood, firebase tries to use my { merge: true } and put it into the path which for sure throws an error.

How can I merge data in firebase 9, I can't figure it out.

Here my source code:

```
    setDoc(doc(db, "users", userStore.id, "profile_data", "user_profile", { merge: true }), {
        country: selectedCountry.value,
        year_born: selectedYearBorn.value,        
        gender: selectedGender.value,
        profile_complete: true
    }).then( () => {
        console.log("success")
    }).catch(() => {
        console.log("alert")
    })
```

I guess I places the { merge: true } option at the wrong place but  where do I have to put it?

Btw: The connection to the database works perfectly fine, so there is no connection problem or anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you `console.log(db, userStore.id)` before the `setDoc` and share a screenshot of the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options are to be passed to the `setDoc`  operation, but you're passing them to `doc()`.

To solve this:

```
setDoc(doc(db, "users", userStore.id, "profile_data", "user_profile"), {
    country: selectedCountry.value,
    year_born: selectedYearBorn.value,        
    gender: selectedGender.value,
    profile_complete: true
}, { merge: true })
```